# Cross Join on Itself RStudio

Tags: r, combinations, cross-join

I am interested in finding out how to convert multiple columns in RStudio into two columns by finding every possible combination excluding null values. Here is sample input:

```
Mike Bill Pat Ty 
Bob  Bret Mike null
Dyl  Ty   null null
```

Here is sample output:

```
Mike Bill
Mike Pat
Mike Ty
Bill Pat
Bill Ty
Pat Ty
Bob Bret
Bob Mike
Bret Mike
Dyl Ty
```

Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The `combn()` function combines the elements in all possible ways while maintaining the order.
The `t()` function transposes the result.
You can put these all together at the end with `rbind()`.

```
t(combn(c('Mike', 'Bill', 'Pat', 'Ty'), 2))
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] "Mike" "Bill"
[2,] "Mike" "Pat" 
[3,] "Mike" "Ty"  
[4,] "Bill" "Pat" 
[5,] "Bill" "Ty"  
[6,] "Pat"  "Ty" 
t(combn(c('Bob', 'Bret', 'Mike', NULL), 2))
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] "Bob"  "Bret"
[2,] "Bob"  "Mike"
[3,] "Bret" "Mike"
t(combn(c('Dyl', 'Ty', NULL, NULL), 2))
     [,1]  [,2]
[1,] "Dyl" "Ty"
```